# regular expression split by = and !=

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm bangging my head trying to figure out what's the correct regular expression to split this string:

```
[ABC]!=[BCD]=
```

Into this splitted result:

- [ABC]
- !=
- [BCD]
- =

My actual regular expression pattern is:

```
(?<=!=|=)|(?=!=|=)
```

But the result i'm getting is:

- [ABC]
- !
- =
- [BCD]
- =

Please help!

Comment: It seems like there are other `*=` operators that you're allowing, do you have a complete list of the ones that are acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, that part of the regex pattern is not relevant... actually my regex is a lot more complex, but I just need to solve this last part of the puzzle.. I'll edit the question to remove non-relevant parts... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much simpler:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, "(!?=)");
```

gives you `["[ABC]", "!=", "[BCD]", "="]`.

Comment: Wow! I really didn't know that if you put your search pattern inside round brackets the Split method will include the match... where in the hell is that documented?!.. thanks a lot man!

Comment: "where in the hell is that documented?!" and "Regular Expressions"!  You crack me up :)

Comment: I think it's [pretty well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(!=)|(=)|(\[.*?\])`

Comment: yep, you are right, but I marked Tim Pietzcker answer as correct for a few seconds... thanks anyway!